# How to limit standard output at tclsh command line?

Tags: tcl, tclsh

When running commands interactively at the tclsh command line, is there a way to truncate how much of a return value gets printed to stdout?

For example, this will take a very long time because the return value will print to stdout.

```
tclsh> set a [lrepeat 500000000 x]
```

I know I can add a dummy command in the same line, but this is an ad hoc solution.  Is there some I could set in my ~/.tclshrc to truncate stdout to a finite length?

```
tclsh> set a [lrepeat 500000000 x] ; puts ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is an XY-problem (as turning off or swallowing prints to `stdout` seems to satisfy the OP), but the actual question was:

> Is there some I could set in my ~/.tclshrc to truncate stdout to a
> finite length?

You can use an interceptor on `stdout` (and/ or, `stderr`) to cap strings to a default limit:

```
oo::class create capped {
  variable max
  constructor {m} {
    set max $m
  } 
  method initialize {handle mode} {
    if {$mode ne "write"} {error "can't handle reading"}
    return {finalize initialize write}
  }
  method finalize {handle} {
    # NOOP
  }
  
  method write {handle bytes} {
    if {[string length $bytes] > $max} {
      set enc [encoding system]
      set str [encoding convertfrom $enc $bytes]
      set newStr [string range $str 0 $max-1]
      if {[string index $str end] eq "\n"} {
        append newStr "\n"
      }
      set bytes [encoding convertto $enc $newStr]
    }
    return $bytes
  }
}
```

Using [`chan push`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.html#M32) and [`chan pop`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.html#M30) you may turn on/off capping to, e.g., 30 characters:

```
% chan push stdout [capped new 30]
serial1
% puts [string repeat € 35]
€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€
% chan pop stdout
% puts [string repeat € 35]
€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€
```

---

Some remarks:

- You can use an object, a namespace, or a proc offering the required interface of [channel interceptors](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/transchan.html) (initialize, write, ...); I prefer objects.
- Ad `write`: You want to cap based on a character-based limit, not a byte-level one. However, `write` receives a string of bytes, not a string of characters. So, you need to be careful when enforcing the limit (back-transform the byte string into a char string, and vice versa, using [`encoding convertfrom`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/encoding.html#M6) and [`encoding convertto`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/encoding.html#M7)).
- Similar, whether certain values of `max` might not be a good choice or the value range should be restricted. E.g., a `max` of 1 or 0 will turn off the basic REPL (the prompt `%` ), effectively.
- As for `tclshrc`: You may want place the interceptor definition and `chan push` call therein, to enable capping per default?

Comment: Very cool.   This is in my ~/.tclshrc file now.  I added an extra line `append newStr "...\n (stdout capped to $max bytes)\n"` near the end of the write method.    I've used channel interceptors before and I'm curious about other applications.

Answer (score 1):

tclsh is a REPL, and the "P" there is what you're seeing. Without digging into the source, I don't know that there's a simple way to accomplish exactly what you're asking.

If I remember to do it, the `list` command is useful to provide no output

```
set a [lrepeat 500000000 x]; list
```

or perhaps something informative

```
set a [lrepeat 500000000 x]; llength $a
```

If you want to get programmy:

```
proc i {val} {set ::tcl_interactive $val}
```

Then do `i off` or `i 0` or `i false` to turn off interactivity and then execute the commands with large results. Going non-interactive silences the printing of command results, but it also turns off the prompt which could be confusing. Restore interactivity with `i on` or `i 1` or `i true`

Comment: That's pretty interesting.  I thought that ::tcl_interactive was a read-only variable, but not so!

Comment: @ChrisHeithoff Check another option (capping) in my answer